# Split into columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, split

I want to make 1500 rows x 3 columns data from below output. First [0,1,2] columns there was some information and I deleted them by using .drop . At this point, I have difficulty about dividing them to the columns. Could you help me? Thanks!

```
excel_book_1 ='air-accumulation-c5-v2.csv'
df_1 = pd.read_csv(excel_book_1)
df_1.drop([0,1,2], inplace=True)
df_1.columns = range(df_1.shape[1])
df_1

           0
3   1 0 0.01
4   2 0 0.02
5   3 0 0.03
6   4 0 0.04
7   5 0 0.05
... ...
1498    1496 5.036537684491391e-09 14.96
1499    1497 5.036727502175594e-09 14.97
1500    1498 5.036981901795193e-09 14.98
1501    1499 5.037296660302418e-09 14.99
1502    1500 5.037647012557997e-09 15
1500 rows × 1 columns
```

Comment: I got this error: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 4

Comment: Do you copy/paste the 10 first lines of your csv, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['0'].str.split(' ',expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your csv file looks like:

```
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
1 0 0.01
2 0 0.02
3 0 0.03
4 0 0.04
5 0 0.05
```

You can use `pd.read_csv` like that:

```
>>> pd.read_csv(excel_book_1, sep=' ', skiprows=3, header=None)
   0  1     2
0  1  0  0.01
1  2  0  0.02
2  3  0  0.03
3  4  0  0.04
4  5  0  0.05
```